# Filling out a diagonal matrix with wrap around Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a matrix that I would like to fill out with VBA. The loop uses information in one column to get who many columns it should value.

I have matrix row and column headers to assist the loop like so:

```
    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |... | 23
0
--
1
--
2
--
3
--
4
--
5
--
...
23
```

The numbers 0 - 23 represent the hours of the day. There is data in AA that tells me how many columns across the value in AB should be pasted.

For example if `Cells(2, 27)` Row 2 column 27 (AA) = 6 then the value in column AB should be placed in row 2 (hour 0) x times. If the column iterator reaches a value of more than 25 then the column iterator should go back to 2 and finish out.

For example, if on row 23 there is a value of 6 in column AA(avg_time_here) then column Y should get valued and then columns B, C, D, E and F should get valued. The issues is I do not know how to value columns B-F. I can get Y filled out but as soon as I have to go back to column B I do not know how.

What I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatrixFill()

Dim avg_hrl_arr As Double    ' avgerage hourly arrivals
Dim avg_time_here As Integer ' avgerage time here
Dim hour_value As Integer    ' the value of the current hour
Dim y As Integer             ' row iterator for avg_time_here
Dim xCol As Integer          ' What column to go to
Dim x As Integer             ' for loop iterator
Dim LoopCount As Integer     ' How many times the loop has run
Dim NumCols As Integer       ' How many columns to fill out
Dim i As Integer             ' if statement for loop iterator

y = 21
LoopCount = 0

Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

Do While Cells(y, 27) <> ""
    hour_value = Cells(y, 1)
    avg_time_here = Cells(y, 27)
    NumCols = avg_time_here
    avg_hrl_arr = Cells(y, 28)
    'MsgBox ("The hour = " & hour_value & vbNewLine & "There are on average " & avg_hrl_arr & " hourly arrivals." & vbNewLine & "Avg time here = " & avg_time_here & " hours.")
    xCol = (avg_time_here + hour_value + 1)
    ' loop through columns
    Debug.Print "Hour Value Initialized to: " & hour_value
    Debug.Print "Average Time Here Initialized to: " & avg_time_here
    Debug.Print "NumCols Initialized to: " & NumCols
    Debug.Print "Average Hourly Arrivals Initialized to: " & avg_hrl_arr
    Debug.Print "xCol Initialized to: " & xCol
    For x = (hour_value + 2) To xCol
        Debug.Print "X is currently " & x
        If x > 25 Then
            Debug.Print "NumCols is currently " & NumCols
            i = 2
            Do While NumCols > 0
                Cells(y, i) = avg_hrl_arr
                NumCols = NumCols - 1
                Debug.Print "NumCols is now " & NumCols
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            GoTo NextYValue
        End If
        Cells(y, x) = avg_hrl_arr
        LoopCount = LoopCount + 1
        NumCols = NumCols - 1
        Debug.Print "Y = " & y
        Debug.Print "LoopCount = " & LoopCount
        Debug.Print "NumCols = " & NumCols & " left"
    Next x
```

NextYValue:
        y = y + 1
        LoopCount = 0
    Loop

End Sub

Sample Data:

```
| avg_time_here | avg_hrl_arr 
|---------------|-------------
|7              | 4.47        
|7              | 3.54        
|6              | 3.11        
|6              | 2.55        
|7              | 2.40        
|7              | 2.34        
|6              | 3.15        
|6              | 4.68        
|6              | 6.44
|5              | 8.63
|6              | 10.00
|6              | 10.60
|6              | 10.68
|6              | 10.31
|6              | 9.92
|6              | 10.05
|6              | 9.89
|6              | 9.98
|6              | 10.23
|6              | 10.00
|6              | 9.37
|6              | 8.41
|6              | 7.32
|6              | 5.82
```

I would like my output to look like the picture:
[image: Properly Filled Out Matrix that was done by hand]

Comment: What's the problem?. also, would help if you post some sample data.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I added my updated code, sample data and the desired output.

Comment: got it. working on it.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I got it figured out and will post my code I'm sure a more elegant solution can be thought up. I will post what I have

Comment: I saw that you may have your data in different columns, but my approach may give you an alternative for other needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach.

Convert the data to an structured Excel table like this:

[image]

Customize the code to fit your needs:

```
Sub MatrixFill()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim matrixSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataTable As ListObject
    Dim dataCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim matrixSheetName As String
    Dim sheetDataName As String
    Dim dataTableName As String
    Dim matrixInitialCell As String
    Dim cellCounter As Integer
    Dim columnOffset As Integer
    Dim columnResize As Integer

    Dim avg_hrl_arr As Double    ' avgerage hourly arrivals
    Dim avg_time_here As Integer ' avgerage time here
    Dim hour_value As Integer    ' the value of the current hour

    ' Initialize objects
    matrixSheetName = "Sheet2"
    Set matrixSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(matrixSheetName)

    dataTableName = "TableData"
    sheetDataName = "Sheet1"
    Set dataTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetDataName).ListObjects(dataTableName)

    ' Clear initial range
    matrixSheet.Range("B2:B25").Clear

    matrixInitialCell = "A1"

    ' Loop through each data cell
    For Each dataCell In dataTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells

        cellCounter = cellCounter + 1

        ' Get data values
        avg_time_here = dataCell.Value
        avg_hrl_arr = dataCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        ' Resize if there are more than 24 columns
        If (cellCounter + avg_time_here - 1) > 24 Then
            columnResize = (cellCounter + avg_time_here - 1) - 24
        Else
            columnResize = 0
        End If

        ' Fill matrix
        matrixSheet.Range(matrixInitialCell).Offset(cellCounter, cellCounter).Resize(1, avg_time_here - columnResize).Value = avg_hrl_arr

        ' Fill from begining the ones that are left
        If columnResize > 0 Then
            matrixSheet.Range(matrixInitialCell).Offset(cellCounter, 1).Resize(1, columnResize).Value = avg_hrl_arr
        End If

    Next dataCell

End Sub
```